# Docker search command with criteria shows inconsistent results

Tags: java, docker

`docker search java` shows the output as:

```
NAME                         DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
java                         Java is a concurrent, class-based, and obj...   756       [OK]       
anapsix/alpine-java          Oracle Java 8 (and 7) with GLIBC 2.21 over...   66                   [OK]
develar/java                                                                 42                   [OK]
isuper/java-oracle           This repository contains all java releases...   28                   [OK]
lwieske/java-8               Oracle Java 8 Container - Full + Slim - Ba...   17                   [OK]
nimmis/java-centos           This is docker images of CentOS 7 with dif...   8                    [OK]
nimmis/java                  This is docker images of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ...   7                    [OK]
1science/java                Java Docker images based on Alpine Linux        6                    [OK]
andreluiznsilva/java         Docker images for java applications             5                    [OK]
```

and several other rows.

Restricting image to only 10 stars using `docker search -s 10 java` shows:

```
NAME                  DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
node                  Node.js is a JavaScript-based platform for...   1899      [OK]       
java                  Java is a concurrent, class-based, and obj...   756       [OK]       
anapsix/alpine-java   Oracle Java 8 (and 7) with GLIBC 2.21 over...   66                   [OK]
develar/java                                                          42                   [OK]
isuper/java-oracle    This repository contains all java releases...   28                   [OK]
lwieske/java-8        Oracle Java 8 Container - Full + Slim - Ba...   17                   [OK]
```

Why the additional Node image is shown in the second listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is when passing the stars parameter (-s), the results are ordered by stars descendingly. If you go to (filtering only by java)

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=java&starCount=0,

you won't see the node image until the 2nd page, but as soon as you filter by stars, it seems to be sorting also by stars

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=java&starCount=1

**UPDATE**

I have detected different results for the same search, sometimes including the node sometimes not:

http://recordit.co/SBwQa4UPkT

Comment: So there does seem to be inconsistency?

Comment: It seems so. I was checking the code but I am not a go expert and I couldnt find anything